# Ban requests with discord.js

Tags: javascript, request, discord.js

I'm trying to `ban` an `array of userIDs` stored in a `database` using a `request` with the `PUT` method.

But unfortunately I ran into the problem, that nothing happens after starting the program.

This is my code:

```
const headers = {Authorization: token}

function Ban(guild, members) {
    const DB = require('./database.json');
    const IDs = DB.userIDs;

    for (let i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
        members = IDs[i];

        requests.put(`https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/${guild}/bans/${members}`, {
            headers: headers
        }, function (err, response, body) {

        if (err) throw err;
            console.log(chalk.blue("Process | Status Code: " + response.statusCode));
        })
    }
}
```

When I display the status code I get the following output:

[image]

*I'm calling the function somewhere else in the code*

Comment: 401 means unauthorized. Seems that your request lacks some authorization header. Considering that you do set something like a token, either that token is empty or invalid, or the server does not look at header "Authorization" but something else.

Comment: you were right. the documentation states that the header has to be done a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Gulubus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4978205/glubus) advice, I rechecked the right way to use headers:

```
const headers = {Authorization: `Bot ${token}`}
```

[image]

and the users were succesfully banned.